# WildFly 9 security vulnerability Issue

Tags: java, security, wildfly, wildfly-9

I have a java application which is hosted in **WildFly 9**. It was noted that recently someone has added/Injected a text file and a php file which had just a text saying hacked by somename.. Now I found the files inside *wildfly-9.0.2.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp...* this path. Then I deleted them. Seems there is no harm other than that.

I searched if there is such vulnerability in wildfly 9, but I couldn't find any information like that or a solution. Is there a solution to fix this security issue without upgrading wildfly to a newer version? or should this be fixed in a proxy server level?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Very unlikely that you faced real 0day in Java/JVM or application server, much more realistic that there is some API that allow to upload files anonymously and then open them from url. Check logs for details.

Comment: There is no fix version for WildFly 9, you have to upgrade to latest to be covered securely.